# magento 2.0.7 sampledata:deploy|remove fatal error after composer update

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0.7

I've updated magento from 2.0.4 to 2.0.7 via composer.
And then I tried to remove sample data using CLI

```
php70 bin/magento sampledata:remove
```

and got following error.

```
     PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to 
Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput::__construct() 
    must be of the type array, object given, called in
 /srv/mat24/web/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php 
on line 97 and defined in 
    /srv/mat24/web/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArrayInput.php:37
        Stack trace:
        #0 /srv/mat24/web/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(97): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
        #1 /srv/mat24/web/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Symfony\Compone...', Array)
        #2 /srv/mat24/web/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Symfony\Compone...', Array)
        #3 /srv/mat24/web/var/generation/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArrayInputFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\Obje in /srv/mat24/web/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArrayInput.php on line 37
```

What could be the reason and how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This is an (unresolved) issue with ArrayInputFactory in production mode (see [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2604) and [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7604)). Since your command is "one shot" you can switch your store in developer mode, launch the command, and then switch back to production mode.

**BUT**... [sample data cannot really be removed](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/sample-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$./bin/magento setup:upgrade 
$ ./bin/magento cache:flush
```

And then remove the sample content

Comment: I did it many times. Thanx, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Have you done all these steps after upgrading :**

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex.

Delete folders except .htaccess file from , m2_root_directory > pub > static  and then m2_root_directory  > var  > view_preprocessed.

Flush Magento cache by typing “php bin/magento cache:flush” in CMD.

Then recheck it once.